# Elementor custom query with two WP_Query requests

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I'm using WordPress and Elementor. There are 2 post types named "albums" and "clips". The clips post type stores video clips for specific album under albums post type. A custom Elementor query displays all albums under which user has uploaded the clips.
When the queries are tested on a testing page, it works fine. But when included under Elementor custom query, it doesn't work. Here is the code,

```
function user_contributed( $query ) {
  // initialize array
  $albums[] = '';
  // Get logged in user id  
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
if(isset($user_id) && !empty($user_id)){
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  // Get user email ID
  $user_email = $user_info->user_email;
  // Get the user contributed clips from "clips" post type
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'clips', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'user_email', 'value' => $user_email, 'compare' => '=' ), 'relation' => 'AND', array( 'key' => 'clip_status', 'value' => 'ready', 'compare' => '=' ) ),
        );
$contributed_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($contributed_query->have_posts()) {
if($contributed_query->post_count > 0){
  while($contributed_query->have_posts() ) {
    $contributed_query->the_post(); $postid = get_the_ID();
    // Get album ID from ACF field
    $albumid = get_field( "album_id", $postid );
    if(!in_array($albumid, $albums)){ $albums[] = $albumid; }
  }
}
}
// Get all albums from "album" post type, where logged-in user has contributed
$query->set( 'post_type', [ 'albums' ] );
$query->set( 'post__in', $albums );
}
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/user_contributed', 'user_contributed' );
```

I think the first query is overwriting or conflicting with the main query. I tried wp_reset_postdata, wp_reset_query and pre_get_posts but didn't work. The [Elementor custom query documentation](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/) wasn't helpful. Is it possible to execute a query before the main query?

I tried wp_reset_postdata, wp_reset_query and pre_get_posts but didn't work.